# Custom Wix UI Looping

Tags: dialog, wix, installation

I have been creating a wix installer and have got the majority working except the UI.

I needed to add two dialog boxes, so I chose the "Mondo" UI sequence and added my dialogs as appropriate.

It likes it (see code below for the UI sequencing code) but when I add the regionSelectDlg and VariantSelectDlg lines in, when the user clicks "install" the installer loops back and restarts.

Is there anything someone can see, or has someone experienced this before? I've looked at what's different between the sequencing and the mondo and can't see any major differences except my additions.

```
    <UI Id="customWIXUI">
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
      <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Mondo" />

      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="RegionSelectDlg" >LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="RegionSelectDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="RegionSelectDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VariantSelectDlg" />

      <Publish Dialog="VariantSelectDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="RegionSelectDlg" />
      <Publish Dialog="VariantSelectDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg"/>

      <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="TypicalButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="CustomButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="CompleteButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallTypical" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="3">WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="4">WixUI_InstallMode = "Repair" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Remove"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeDlg" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "Update"</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="ChangeButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    </UI>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because of incorrect `Order` attributes. I'd try removing all of yours and then re-adding them from the top down sequentially (presumably ignoring your ExitDialog statement). For example,

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish><Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeDlg" Order="3">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="RegionSelectDlg" Order="4">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
```

That ought to provide a working configuration that you can then modify as you need.